# Что это и как с ним работать

Tags: php, c++

Сразу говорю начинающий. Столкнулся с вот этим шифром в PHP:
DIST($x1,$x2,$x3,$x4)
Не пойму что оно такое, что бы работать с ним в С++.
Буду рад любой подсказке направляющей к положительному решению...

Comment: функция DIST с 4 аргументами. Причём тут C++ ?

Comment: В каком контексте вы столкнулись с этим . И в чем  связь между c++ и php ?

Comment: Столкнулся с этой как выше ответили функцией в коде Clickermann (код плавного движения курсора). он написан на PHP. так как та прога работает через раз. Пишу его на С++. ну и возникают естественно проблемы с переводом языка в язык

Comment: Вот здесь этот код http://crapware.aidf.org/forum/index.php?topic=1583.0 в комментарий (Декабрь 01, 2014, 07:33:30)

Comment: Вызов функции DIST, сама функция является внутренней функцией встроенного языка сценариев. Можете найти ее описание в справочнике программы Clickermann, находит расстояние между двумя точками по координатам.